# What are the values of $x$, $y$ and $r$ if $\cot\theta=\frac{5}{6}$ and $\csc\theta <0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I solved this problem, where $r$ is a radius of a circle. Is my solution right?

What are the values of $x$, $y$ and $r$ if $\cot\theta=\frac{5}{6}$ and $\csc\theta <0$?

Since $\cot\theta$ is positive and $\csc\theta$ is negative, $\theta$ must be on the third quadrant. Therefore, the values of $x$ and $y$ must be both negative. Since $\cot\theta=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$, $\sin\theta=y$ and $\cos\theta=x$, then $x=-5$ and $y=-6$. I can use the Pythagorean Theorem to solve for $r$.

$r^2=x^2+y^2$

$r^2=25+36$

$r^2=61$

$r=\sqrt{61}$

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Note: $-1\leq\sin\theta\leq1$ and likewise for $\cos\theta$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 yeah. now I'm confused. how should I solve for both of the functions?

Comment: Why is $(x,y)$ necessarily $(-5,-6)$ and not any other point in the third quadrant with that ratio, such as $(-2.5,3)$?

Comment: @harpey1111: You may use some trigonometric identities such as $\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude that $x=-5$ and $y=-6$.

You are right that it is in the third quadrant.

$$\cot \theta = \frac{r\cos \theta}{r \sin \theta}=\frac{x}y=\frac{5}{6}.$$

Hence, we have the half-line:

$$6x=5y, x < 0.$$

Any point on the half line satisfies the condition.